# Save a copy of Workbook, Filter data and delete the filtered data and the loop

Tags: excel, vba

I have a large data set in a workbook with 3 sheets (Data, Data1, Data2) containing data 5000 rows. ColumnA contains multiple 3 letter codes. (there are altogether 160 distinct 3 letter codes -ABC)

I wish to save a copy of the workbook in my C:\ and then go to sheet "Data", filter out the first 3 letter code-ABC, select the rest of data and delete it and save as 'ABC'. Do the same for the other sheets "Data1" and "Data2"

Then I will like to do Next or Loop the rest of the 160 distinct codes - (ABB, ACB, BEC, HGN, etc)

So the result will be 160 workbooks with names ABC, ABB, containing only their respective data.

I have put a code together which does it for ABC but I can not make it to go back and recreate the scenarios using the filtered data.

```
 Sub Tcode()


 Dim tcode As String
 Dim Tcode As String
 Dim ColNumber As Integer  
 Dim FPath As String
 Dim r As Range




'Do While ColNumber < 162
'Save a copy of the Datasheet
        'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="P:\Work\New\R1H.xlsm", FileFormat:= _
      ' xlOpenXMLWorkbookMacroEnabled, CreateBackup:=False

      FPath = "P:\Work\New\"

          With Sheets("tcode")
                 For Each r In .Range("a2", .Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
         If r.Value <> "" Then
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

      End If

 'Go to Data Sheet and filter out the tcode and delete the rest
 Sheets("Data").Select
 Rows("1:1").Select
  Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Sheets("tcode").Range("A2").Value
 ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$W$15521").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
 "R1H", "RA2", "RA3", "RA4", "RA7", "RA9", "RAE", "RAJ", "RAL", "RAN", "RAP", "RAS", "RAX", _
  "RBA", "RBB", "RBD", "RBK", "RBL", "RBN", "RBQ", "RBS", "RBT", "RBV", "RBZ", "RC1", "RC3", _
   "RC9", "RCB", "RCD", "RCF", "RCU", "RCX", "RD1", "RD3", "RD7", "RD8", "RDD", "RDE", "RDU", _
   "RDZ", "RE9", "REF", "REM", "REN", "REP", "RET", "RF4", "RFF", "RFR", "RFS", "RFW", "RGM", _
   "RGN", "RGP", "RGQ", "RGR", "RGT", "RH8", "RHM", "RHQ", "RHU", "RHW", "RJ1", "RJ2", "RJ6", _
   "RJ7", "RJC", "RJD", "RJE", "RJF", "RJL", "RJN", "RJR", "RJZ", "RK5", "RK9", "RKB", "RKE", _
   "RL1", "RL4", "RLN", "RLQ", "RLT", "RLU", "RM1", "RM2", "RM3", "RMC", "RMP", "RN3", "RN5", _
   "RN7", "RNA", "RNL", "RNQ", "RNS", "RNZ", "RP4", "RP5", "RP6", "RPA", "RPC", "RPY", "RQ3", _
   "RQ6", "RQ8", "RQM", "RQQ", "RQW", "RQX", "RR1", "RR7", "RR8", "RRF", "RRJ", "RRK", "RRV", _
   "RT3", "RTD", "RTE", "RTF", "RTG", "RTH", "RTK", "RTP", "RTR", "RTX", "RV8", "RVJ", "RVL", _
   "RVR", "RVV", "RVW", "RVY", "RW3", "RW6", "RWA", "RWD", "RWE", "RWF", "RWG", "RWH", "RWJ", _
   "RWP", "RWW", "RWY", "RX1", "RXC", "RXF", "RXH", "RXK", "RXL", "RXN", "RXP", "RXQ", "RXR", _
   "RXW", "RYJ", "RYR"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
 Range("A99").Select
 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
 Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
 Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
 Selection.AutoFilter
 ActiveWorkbook.Save
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 'Range("A99:W15520").Select
 'Selection.End(xlUp).Select
 'Range("A99").Select


 'Goto Appendix sheet and filter out the tcode and delete the rest
 Sheets("Appendix").Select
  Rows("1:1").Select
 Selection.AutoFilter
 ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$W$20481").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
 "R1H", "RA2", "RA3", "RA4", "RA7", "RA9", "RAE", "RAJ", "RAL", "RAN", "RAP", "RAS", "RAX", _
 "RBA", "RBB", "RBD", "RBK", "RBL", "RBN", "RBQ", "RBS", "RBT", "RBV", "RBZ", "RC1", "RC3", _
 "RC9", "RCB", "RCD", "RCF", "RCU", "RCX", "RD1", "RD3", "RD7", "RD8", "RDD", "RDE", "RDU", _
 "RDZ", "RE9", "REF", "REM", "REN", "REP", "RET", "RF4", "RFF", "RFR", "RFS", "RFW", "RGM", _
 "RGN", "RGP", "RGQ", "RGR", "RGT", "RH8", "RHM", "RHQ", "RHU", "RHW", "RJ1", "RJ2", "RJ6", _
 "RJ7", "RJC", "RJD", "RJE", "RJF", "RJL", "RJN", "RJR", "RJZ", "RK5", "RK9", "RKB", "RKE", _
 "RL1", "RL4", "RLN", "RLQ", "RLT", "RLU", "RM1", "RM2", "RM3", "RMC", "RMP", "RN3", "RN5", _
 "RN7", "RNA", "RNL", "RNQ", "RNS", "RNZ", "RP4", "RP5", "RP6", "RPA", "RPC", "RPY", "RQ3", _
 "RQ6", "RQ8", "RQM", "RQQ", "RQW", "RQX", "RR1", "RR7", "RR8", "RRF", "RRJ", "RRK", "RRV", _
 "RT3", "RTD", "RTE", "RTF", "RTG", "RTH", "RTK", "RTP", "RTR", "RTX", "RV8", "RVJ", "RVL", _
 "RVR", "RVV", "RVW", "RVY", "RW3", "RW6", "RWA", "RWD", "RWE", "RWF", "RWG", "RWH", "RWJ", _
  "RWP", "RWW", "RWY", "RX1", "RXC", "RXF", "RXH", "RXK", "RXL", "RXN", "RXP", "RXQ", "RXR", _
 "RXW", "RYJ", "RYR"), Operator:=xlFilterValues

 Range("A126").Select
 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
 Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
 Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
  Selection.AutoFilter
 ActiveWorkbook.Save
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
 Application.ScreenUpdating = False
'Selection.End(xlUp).Select
'Range("A126").Select




  'Goto Appendix sheet and filter out the tcode and delete the rest
  Sheets("Appendix 2").Select
  Rows("1:1").Select
  Selection.AutoFilter
  ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$5441").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Array( _
  "R1H", "RA2", "RA3", "RA4", "RA7", "RA9", "RAE", "RAJ", "RAL", "RAN", "RAP", "RAS", "RAX", _
    "RBA", "RBB", "RBD", "RBK", "RBL", "RBN", "RBQ", "RBS", "RBT", "RBV", "RBZ", "RC1", "RC3", _
  "RC9", "RCB", "RCD", "RCF", "RCU", "RCX", "RD1", "RD3", "RD7", "RD8", "RDD", "RDE", "RDU", _
  "RDZ", "RE9", "REF", "REM", "REN", "REP", "RET", "RF4", "RFF", "RFR", "RFS", "RFW", "RGM", _
  "RGN", "RGP", "RGQ", "RGR", "RGT", "RH8", "RHM", "RHQ", "RHU", "RHW", "RJ1", "RJ2", "RJ6", _
  "RJ7", "RJC", "RJD", "RJE", "RJF", "RJL", "RJN", "RJR", "RJZ", "RK5", "RK9", "RKB", "RKE", _
  "RL1", "RL4", "RLN", "RLQ", "RLT", "RLU", "RM1", "RM2", "RM3", "RMC", "RMP", "RN3", "RN5", _
  "RN7", "RNA", "RNL", "RNQ", "RNS", "RNZ", "RP4", "RP5", "RP6", "RPA", "RPC", "RPY", "RQ3", _
 "RQ6", "RQ8", "RQM", "RQQ", "RQW", "RQX", "RR1", "RR7", "RR8", "RRF", "RRJ", "RRK", "RRV", _
 "RT3", "RTD", "RTE", "RTF", "RTG", "RTH", "RTK", "RTP", "RTR", "RTX", "RV8", "RVJ", "RVL", _
 "RVR", "RVV", "RVW", "RVY", "RW3", "RW6", "RWA", "RWD", "RWE", "RWF", "RWG", "RWH", "RWJ", _
 "RWP", "RWW", "RWY", "RX1", "RXC", "RXF", "RXH", "RXK", "RXL", "RXN", "RXP", "RXQ", "RXR", _
 "RXW", "RYJ", "RYR"), Operator:=xlFilterValues
 Range("A36").Select
 Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
 Range(Selection, ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
 Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
 Selection.AutoFilter
 ActiveWorkbook.Save
 Application.DisplayAlerts = False
   Application.ScreenUpdating = False

      ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs FPath & r.Value & ".XLS"
    Next r
  End With

 End Sub
```

It will be great if someone can point me in the right direction.
  Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

This will do just that. It copies all the sheets in a file (no matter how many there are). It copies the first row of each sheet (assuming the column names are there). But of course, after the first row, it will copy only the rows that start with the three letter code for that sheet. It saves each sheet with the appropiate three letter code as a name.

Alter the directory where the sheets need to be saved in the code!

If you want to keep all the sheets open, after saving, delete the line newworkbook.close. (WIth 160 sheets, I guess you don;t want that ;) )

If there are formulas in the sheets, it may all not work properly, you'll have to test ; the code may need some alteration then.

MIND YOU IT IS SLOW, IT WILL TAKE A WHILE

```
Sub DoIt()
    Dim ThreeletterCodes As New Collection
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Cnt As Long
    Dim Code
    Dim Worksheet As Worksheet, NewWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim NewWorkbook As Workbook
    Dim Row As Long, NewRow As Long

    Dim DestPath As String

    DestPath = "E:\TEMP\" ' use \ at end of path

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
        Cnt = .UsedRange.Rows.Count
        For i = 1 To Cnt
            If Len(.Cells(i, 1).Value) = 3 Then
                On Error Resume Next
                ThreeletterCodes.Add .Cells(i, 1).Value, .Cells(i, 1).Value
                On Error GoTo 0
            End If
        Next
    End With
    ' All unique three letter codes now in the collection
    ' Speed up execution considerably by not calculating and no screenupdates
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    ' Iterate through all the codes
    For Each Code In ThreeletterCodes
        ' Make a new file for each code
        Set NewWorkbook = Application.Workbooks.Add
        ' Iterate through all the sheets in a file
        For Each Worksheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
            ' Make a new worksheet in the new file; or select an existing one if there is one already
            If Worksheet.Index > NewWorkbook.Worksheets.Count Then
                Set NewWorksheet = NewWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=NewWorkbook.Worksheets(NewWorkbook.Worksheets.Count))  ' Add sheet after last worksheet
            Else
                Set NewWorksheet = NewWorkbook.Worksheets(Worksheet.Index)
            End If
            ' make the sheets have the same name as in the original file
            NewWorksheet.Name = Worksheet.Name
            ' Always copy first row with Column names
            Worksheet.Rows(1).Copy Destination:=NewWorksheet.Rows(1)
            ' And copy all the rest if first cell has the three letters
            Cnt = Worksheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count
            NewRow = 2
            For Row = 2 To Cnt
                ' Status message
                Application.StatusBar = "Copying Code " & Code & " Sheet " & Worksheet.Name & " Line " & Row: DoEvents
                ' If first cell of row has the three letter code
                If Worksheet.Cells(Row, 1).Value = Code Then
                    ' then copy it to a new row on the destination sheet (in the new file)
                    Worksheet.Rows(Row).Copy Destination:=NewWorksheet.Rows(NewRow)
                    NewRow = NewRow + 1
                End If
            Next
        Next
        ' Save and close the new file
        NewWorkbook.SaveAs DestPath & Code
        NewWorkbook.Close
    Next
    ' Restore speed-up options.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the code. Something seem to be preventing this to run through. I have F8 the code and it gets from the top to the first End With statement and comes back but does nothing and does not move forward.

Comment: Try to restart Excel. Seems like your Excel is confused. There is nothing there where it could hang on. I tested the code: it works. Also, you can remove the line `Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual` after the End With (it will slow down your code quite a bit, but it will help to see what the macro is doing).

It is just basic VBA code, it should work. Try another computer if you can't get it to work.